# Difference between reading a variable using scanf and assignment

Tags: c

```
int main()
{
  int i,j;
  i='c';

  scanf("%d",&j);   // I will read 'c' here 

  printf("%d %d",i,j);

}
```

Output is not same.`'j'` takes garbage value and `'i'` takes ascii value of `'c'`. Can anybody tell what could be the reason ?

Comment: http://c-faq.com/stdio/scanf1a.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You `scanf` says:

```
scanf("%d", &j);
```

With this sentence `scanf` will try to parse (convert) the 'c' character you are using as input to the function into a number. That's way you get *garbage*. C doesn't know how to turn 'c' into a number, because `scanf` is expecting digits.

Try changing that to:

```
scanf("%c", &j);
```

If your `printf` call is like this:

```
printf("%d %d", i, j);
```

You should get the same value, both times: ASCII value of 'c' character.

Comment: But my intention is knowing difference between assigning character to the integer variable and reading character into integer variable using scanf.

Comment: I understand. But in order to **read a character** into an integer variable, you need to use %c instead of %d. Do keep in mind that scanf is not an assignment function, it's a parsing function (it will try to convert a string into the values your variable represents and your % modifiers tell it to).

Comment: This is not true. He'll only get `99` (the integer value of `'c'`) on the lower byte of `j`, and the rest will be garbage

Comment: @Nathan Fellman: yes this is true. `scanf` will look for digits and try to interpret them as a number. Since there are none, this is invalid input.

Answer (score 1):

You have two issues here.

First of all, you're calling `scanf` with `%d`. This means  `scanf` will look for a decimal character and put it in `j`. It won't find any, so it will leave `j` unchanged.

The first thing you need to do is change `%d` to `%c`.

Now you have another problem.  `j` is an `int`, but you're reading a `char` into it.  A `char` is commonly smaller than an `int`.  Usually a `char` is 8 bits, while an `int` is 32 or 64 bits.  What will happen now is that `scanf` will put the ascii value of `'c'` into the lower byte of `j`, but leave the rest unchanged.

You need to either clear out `j` explicitly:

```
int j = 0;
```

or declare it as a char:

```
char j;
```

This shows the difference between assigning the `int` or using `scanf`.  The `scanf` function doesn't know that `j` is an int.  It guesses what pointers were sent to it based on the format string.  When you use the `%c` format, you're telling `scanf` to treat `&j` as a pointer to a char, while if you explicitly assign it with

`j = 'c'`

The compiler knows that `'c'` is a `char` and `j` is an `int`, and will do the correct conversion for you, including zeroing out the upper bits.

Comment: I initialized j to 0.But after reading 'c' into 'j' i am getting 0 as output.But i should get 99.

Comment: @Jagan: but you also have to change `%d` to `%c`

Answer (score 0):

You are not reading really anything into j. My guess is j will be zero-initialized by your compiler and output 0. Since we really don't know, in your case, what j actually did print out - we can only assume that is the case. In your other example, i, it will likely print the ascii value of 'c' which is 99. If you want to read a character into j, then you also need to change the %d to a %c. But my guess is you really did not intend to use j and it would be replaced with i so you can compare the differences.

Comment: `j` will not necessarily be zero-initialized. Most compilers don't guarantee that at all. In fact, he has garbage because `j` wasn't initialized. If he changes nothing in the code *except* zeroing `j` before the `scanf`, then he will print out `0`.

Comment: @Nathan: It's still possible though I agree he should explicitly initialize because he could be left with a garbage value. We really don't know his output (frankly because the question is poorly worded to understand completely)

Comment: garbage means garbage. That is, not `'c'`.